# mouse gestures C++ library

Tags: c++

I found one port of http://www.bytearray.org/?p=91 but it used boost for multi_array, which I'd like to avoid and would just like to use plan stl if possible. Has anyone ported that flash code to C++ at all? I tried changing the multi_array to vector of vectors and could get up, down, U gestures to work but nothing else (left/right/z/nothing). The demo for the flash library seems to work great for so much.

Since you clicked this topic I assume you have some knowledge of mouse gestures and C++ and would like to know if there is any good plain old C++ mouse gesture library out there that I could plug into my game.

Comment: Read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and [about](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page before posting a question.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://stefan.huberdoc.at/comp/software/mousegestures.html. Looks good.  That is the only library I could find. See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6916/How-to-load-a-dynamic-link-library-DLL-into-a-Micr to load the DLL into Visual Studio.